# Box.com api - "Does file exist" check

Tags: box-api

Why doesn't the box api have an "exists" method for files? Seems like a very common use case.

Because there is no direct method, how do you use the API to tell whether or not a file ID exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the API you can simply [request the metadata for the file](https://docs.box.com/reference#files) with that ID. If the file exists *and* you have access to it, then a full file object will be returned.

Request:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Response:

```
200 OK

{
    "type": "file",
    "id": "5000948880",
    "etag": "3",
    "sha1": "134b65991ed521fcfe4724b7d814ab8ded5185dc",
    "name": "tigers.jpeg",
    ...
}
```

Comment: OK. But how to do that with the SDK? For example the java sdk does not have that endpoint. it's only got one for file or folder.

Comment: Basically i think i have to go new `BoxFolder(api, id).getInfo()` but if that errors out then just get the `BoxFile(api, id).getInfo()` and if neither works it's empty. but that's lame.

Comment: There's no corresponding API endpoint for checking for the existence of an arbitrary item in Box, so you'll have to do it for BoxFolder, BoxFile, BoxWebLink, etc. Please file a feature request for the API at developers.box.com if this would be useful to you.